# clang vs gcc in abstract class handling in compile time

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, abstract-class

One of these [issues](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/346) of nlohmann/json opensource library drew my attention.

I have a minimal reproduction of the case that [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb3681fbf91469c3) under few version of desktop gcc (4.8, 4.9, also tried 5+) but compiles well with mac clang and Android ndk's gcc 4.9

```
#include <limits>

struct base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

int main() {
    (void)numeric_limits<base>::is_signed;
}
```

GCC is trying to instantiate `std::numeric_limits` with base class instead of derived:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/limits: In instantiation of 'struct std::numeric_limits<base>': main.cpp:11:94:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/limits:309:7: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'base'
min() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return _Tp(); }
```

I'm not quite sure if this is a known compiler bug (in case of failure) or feature/relaxed rule (in case of success)

I've tried to work it around with `std::is_abstract` but it does not help, looks like 'short-circuit' evaluation is not happening in enable_if and error stays the same

My question mainly is not how to fix this for gcc but weather this is compiler bug or code bug

---

Edit: added "more minimal" example without any standard library dependency:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  static T bar();
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

struct abstract
{
  virtual ~abstract() = 0;
};

int main()
{
  (void) foo<abstract>::value;
}
```

Compiles on clang 3.9.0, but gcc 7 snapshot emits an error for the invalid return type of `foo<abstract>::bar`.

---

Edit2: I'm a bit surprised that my initial question was edited without my consent, was not aware that SO allows that :) Thanks for help though I think it brought a bit of confusion and wrong answers, mainly because text and code were not connected anymore

Comment: The question is wrong, you have used `std::numeric_limits<base>`, why would it be `std::numeric_limits<derived>`?

Comment: @ShmuelH. The inheritance was a red herring, I have removed `derived` from the example.

Comment: Sorry, it was not my question, it was edited by someone, which surprised me a lot :)

Comment: @OlegBogdanov It wasn't my edit, but both compilers instantiated with the base class, as expected. That was not the reason for the difference between compilers.

Comment: @Oktalist it's totally clear to me now, thanks, it's just edit brought confusion to some answerers, imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not a bug. It is just a bad test.

### Description

The only difference between `GCC` and `clang` in this case is the way they process template class functions:

- `GCC`: All of them in once.
- `clang`: Only the one that has been used.

In our first example, the function `min()` doesn't get called, and therefore, `clang` doesn't has a problem with it. `GCC`, parses all the functions and find out that `min()` is invalid.

In the second example, the same happens: `bar()` doesn't get called by anyone and therefore `clang` is OK about it being ill-formed. But again, `GCC`, have a problem with it, although  hasn't been used anywhere in the program.

### A good test

Saying that something is bad is not enough, let's fix it: this example would fail with both `GCC` and `clang` with almost the same error (`invalid abstract return type ‘base’` or `allocating an object of abstract class type 'base'`).

```
#include <limits>

struct base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

int main() {
    (void)std::numeric_limits<base>::min();
}
```

Comment: No, the test is fine, and the program should fail in both compilers. `numeric_limits<base>` should instantiate all the declarations of the class' member functions, leading to `base` being used as an abstract return type, which is ill-formed.

Comment: @0x499602D2 In the language-lawyer world, you are right. But if a function doesn't get used, generating it would be a waste of resources.

Comment: Clang correctly rejects `template <typename T> struct X { int f(T); }; X<void>{};` though.